# Storing lists in localstorage

Tags: html, jquery, list, html-lists

I am trying to create a page where the items in each unordered list on the page are stored in local storage. So far I've only been able to get one list stored.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to store more than one element ID.

Here's the code that I'm using, with 'm1s1w1' being the id of an unordered list.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var list = document.getElementById('m1s1w1');
    $("#saveAll").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem('todoList', list.innerHTML);
    });
    $("#clearAll").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.clear();
        location.reload();
    });

    loadToDo();

    function loadToDo() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('todoList')){
        list.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('todoList'); 
    }
    }

});
```

Be gentle. I searched for hours and I'm still fairly new to this.

EDIT: Here is the HTML. There are many lists: 'm1s1w1', 'm1s1w2', etc. I removed some of the list items for brevity.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs1">M1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs2">M2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs3">M3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs4">M4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs5">M5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs6">M6</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs1">
    <div id="m1semester1" class="accordion">
        <h3>Semester 1</h3>
            <div>
                <ul id="m1s1w1" class="sortable">
                    <p>Week 1</p>
                    <li class="ui-state-default">
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>
                        <span class="ce">Item 1</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="m1s1w2" class="sortable">
                    <p>Week 2</p>
                    <li class="ui-state-default">
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>
                        <span class="ce">Item 1</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="m1semester2" class="accordion">
        <h3>Semester 2</h3>
            <div>
                <ul id="m1s2w1" class="sortable">
                    <p>Week 1</p>
                    <li class="ui-state-default">
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>
                        <span class="ce">Item 1</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="m1s2w2" class="sortable">
                    <p>Week 2</p>
                    <li class="ui-state-default">
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>
                        <span class="ce">Item 1</span>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <button id="saveAll">Save All</button> |
        <button id="clearAll">Clear All</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So there are many lists? can we see the html?

Comment: Your code works as expected: what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you can loop through the lists and save their content as an array:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#saveAll").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var listContents = [];
    $("ul").each(function(){
       listContents.push(this.innerHTML);
    })
    localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(listContents));
  });

  $("#clearAll").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage.clear();
    location.reload();
  });

  loadToDo();

  function loadToDo() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoList')){
        var listContents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoList'));
        $("ul").each(function(i){
          this.innerHTML = listContents [i];
        })
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: So, I'm adding every list into an array and then using JSON to store the array? That actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: You are storing the contents in an array. `localStorage` can only store strings, so we're converting it into a string using `JSON.stringify()`, and after retrieving the string, converting it back to array using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Is there any way to include appended items to localStorage? I created a button to add new unordered lists (which works fine), but those new unordered lists are not included in the items sent to localStorage. Any ideas?

Comment: @mnaputi if you are clicking `#saveAll` then those should be saved as well... `$("ul")` will find all `<ul>` present in `DOM` regardless of when it was added...

Comment: Would be better if you post a new question with the latest code including a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)